# Find the most recently attached device on Linux VM (XEN or KVM)

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am working on a script where I need to attach a device to VM in AWS and then access it. The device may get attached with the name like `/dev/sdf`, but inside the linux VM, it gets renamed to `/dev/xvdf` or `/dev/nvme2`.

Is there a shell command which can help me get the last (most recently) attached disk? As of now, my solution is more of a hack where I say look for all devices attached to the machine and see if anything matches `/dev/xvdf`, but I don't think that solution translates well into KVM devices.

I am using `ls -Art /dev | grep nvme* | tail -n 1` to see the last machine for KVM, but I don't know how correct this solution might be.

Is there a better more elegant way of doing the same? Some bash or AWS command which returns the last attached disk name?

Comment: What does `lsblk` give you?

Comment: best is to have a uuid on the device

Comment: @stdunbar I am editing the question to add the output of the lsblk